# iText's XMLWorker: how to set width of <td>'s?

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I think this is not working:

```
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 50px">foo</th>
            <th style="width: 70px">bar</th>
            <th style="width: 80px">qux</th>
            <th>obs</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.foo</td>
                <td>@item.bar</td>
                <td>@item.qux</td>
                <td>@item.gloss</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

The columns just end up having a different width from the specified with the style "width: 50px"

Comment: Have you tried setting the widths on the actual `<td>` tags? Since you're not going over the wire the HTML byte count doesn't matter.

Comment: I haven't tried that. I tried setting "%" instead of "px" on all `<th>` tags and that worked (it propagated to `<td>` tags). I wish it happend the same with "px"